# What is "internal vertical borders" / "internal horizontal borders"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The [setBorder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal)
has `vertical` and `horizontal` arguments, what are these exactly?

Answer (score 1):

#### setBorder is a method of class range

And ranges can have more than one cell which leads to border that can be along the edges of the ranges and across the center of the range.

Comment: So other words, if these parameters are not set, then only outer perimeter of the range gets border, otherwise every cell in the range gets it?

Comment: Just try it see what it does.  It won't take you very long to figure it out.